# Is it better to run Codeigniter on PHP5 with or without FastCGI?

Tags: php, fastcgi

I just signed up for BlueHost and one of their PHP config options is PHP5 (FastCGI).

I'm going to start using Codeigniter for as must as I can and was wondering if I should enable FastCGI or now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you setup/migrate/implement the application, and then do a few ab benchmarks with and without FastCGI so you can see for your self?

more info on ab http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html